# Set manual order of piechart using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I conducted a survey under students and now I have a dataset containing 68 records with more than 20 variables. Now I am looking in into one question (one variable): "Would you upload summaries to the platform?"

In order to easily analyze this question, I grouped the answers (using the group_by function of tidyverse), using the following code:

```
upload = data %>%
filter(!is.na(`Upload summaries?`)) %>%
  group_by(`Upload summaries?`) %>%
    summarise(
      number=n()
    ) %>%
    arrange(-number)
```

This results in the following dataset:

```
  `Upload summaries? number
<fct>                <int>
1 Yes                     50
2 No                      18
```

Then I made a piechart using the following code (ggplot2):

```
upload_pie = upload %>%
    ggplot(aes(x="", y=number, fill=`Upload summaries?`)) +
    geom_bar(width=1, stat="identity") +
    geom_text(aes(label=paste(round(number / sum(number) * 100, 0), "%")), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
    coord_polar("y", start=0) +
    labs(fill="Answers", x="", y="", title = "Would you upload summaries to SynopShare?") 
  plot(upload_pie)
```

Which results in the following:
[image]

However, in the legend I want that "Yes" is first and "No" is second. How do I change this?

I already tried using scale_x_discrete() (adding it to the plot):

```
scale_x_discrete(c("Yes", "No")) +
```

But this did not result in any changes.

Moreover, I tried adding the following code:

```
levels(upload$`Upload summaries?`) = c("Yes", "No")
```

But this lead to a misrepresentation of the plot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use scale_fill_discrete with breaks, don't have your data but see the following example:

```
df = data.frame(x=c("a","b"),y=c(3,7))
p1 = ggplot(df,aes(x=1,y=y,fill=x)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity") + coord_polar("y")
p2 = p1 +
scale_fill_discrete(breaks=c("b","a"))
library(patchwork)
p1 + p2
```

[image]